# Why won't my print statements show up in my elif block?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I know there is probably a simple solution to this, but the text I wrote under the `elif` sections in `userName` and `passWord` will not print when a user successfully logs in. Please help!

```
def userName():
    username = "kate"
    userInput = input('Please enter your username:\n')

    while userInput != username:

        if len(userInput) == 0:
            print("Your username can not be blank, please try again!\n")
            userInput = input('Please enter your username.\n')
        elif userInput == username:
            print("Welcome back, " + username)
            print("")
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, that username is not in our system. Please try again!\n")
            userInput = input('Please enter your username.\n')

def passWord():
    password = "stags"
    passInput = input("Please enter your password:\n")

    while passInput != password:

        if len(passInput) == 0:
            print("Your password can not be blank, please try again!\n")
            passInput = input("Please enter your password.\n")
        elif passInput == password:
            print("You have successfully logged in!\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, your password is invalid. Please try again!")
            passInput = input("Please enter your password.\n")

def main():
    print("Hello, let's get started!")
    print("")
    userName()
    passWord()

main()
```

Comment: The if/elif/else blocks are inside while loop, where condition is exactly the opposite of the one in the `elif` part. If you are inside the loop the condition cannot be True. If they enter coorect username/password in the `else` part you will break out of the loop.

Comment: `while passInput != password:` will evaluate to true and your code never enters the loop

Comment: That makes sense. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This was pointed out in the comments above, but if you change

```py
while userInput != username:
```

and

```py
while passInput != password:
```

to

```py
while True:
```

it should work just fine. Then it forces your code to hit the elif statement rather than breaking the loop before printing what you want to say.

Comment: Just used that and got it working, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In python indentation indicates where a code block starts and begins. So in your while loop in passWord() your if..elif..else must be indented exactly one tab in eg.

```
    while passInput != password:

        if len(passInput) == 0:
            print("Your password can not be blank, please try again!\n")
            passInput = input("Please enter your password.\n")
        elif passInput == password:
            print("You have successfully logged in!\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, your password is invalid. Please try again!")
            passInput = input("Please enter your password.\n")
```

Notice how the indentation always goes one tab in for each code block you want to create.

Comment: Note that the indentation problem is [most likely] formatting issue in the question. This does not solve OP problem.